# Modifying $eventargs within Register-ObjectEvent action

Tags: events, powershell, event-handling, odata

In my PowerShell script I am trying to insert a request header in my ODataServices client request. I am using Register-ObjectEvent to do that. This is a technique that works fine in .NET but for some reason does not in PowerShell I am suspecting that PS provides different access to the $EventArgs

```
$proxy = New-ODataServiceProxy "http://localhost.:50055/Service/"

$addAuthenticationHeader =
{   
    $EventArgs.RequestHeaders.Add("X-Authorization", "Y2xhcmsua2VudEBzdXBlci5jb206c3VwZXJtYW46bWFpbg==")
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $proxy -EventName "SendingRequest" -Action $addAuthenticationHeader

$topic = New-Object -TypeName "MyServer.Entities.Topic"
$topic.Name = "hola from PS"
$topic.About = "about"

$proxy.AddObject("Topics", $topic)
$proxy.SaveChanges()
```

When the request goes out on SaveData it does not have the added header in it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem with the properties I modified on `$EventArgs` seemingly having no effect.  I'm not real clear on the details, but when you use the `-Action` parameter of `Register-ObjectEvent` it creates a [`PSEventJob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.pseventjob.aspx) to run your event handler/`ScriptBlock`.  Since `$addAuthenticationHeader` is being run within a `Job`, I suspect the `EventArgs` object that gets passed to it is not the same one that the event was raised with, so the source object never sees the changes you make.

As a workaround, I used the [`Add-Type` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849914.aspx) to define a C# class to do the event handling instead.  I'm not familiar with the API you're using, but it'd look something like this:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using ProxyNamespace;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public static class ProxyHelper
    {
        public static void RegisterSendingRequest(ProxyType proxy)
        {
            proxy.SendingRequest += Proxy_SendingRequest;
        }

        private static void Proxy_SendingRequest(object sender, ProxyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.RequestHeaders.Add(
                "X-Authorization",
                "Y2xhcmsua2VudEBzdXBlci5jb206c3VwZXJtYW46bWFpbg=="
            );
        }
    }
}
"@ -ReferencedAssemblies $ProxyAssemblyPath;
```

You'll need to replace `ProxyNamespace`, `ProxyType`, `ProxyEventArgs`, and `$ProxyAssemblyPath` with appropriate values, then just replace this...

```
$addAuthenticationHeader =
{   
    $EventArgs.RequestHeaders.Add("X-Authorization", "Y2xhcmsua2VudEBzdXBlci5jb206c3VwZXJtYW46bWFpbg==")
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $proxy -EventName "SendingRequest" -Action $addAuthenticationHeader
```

...with this...

```
[StackOverflow.ProxyHelper]::RegisterSendingRequest($proxy);
```